# Why are 4 vertices created from a query with 1 `addV()` clause?

Tags: azure-cosmosdb, gremlin, azure-cosmosdb-gremlinapi

Per the [Tinkerpop documentation](http://tinkerpop.apache.org/docs/current/reference/#addproperty-step), I would expect the following query to create 1 new vertex with 5 properties when passed to Azure CosmosDB.

```
g.V()
  .addV('ImpactArea')
  .property('partitionKey', '1')
  .property('docId', 'N3TWjll8Ryba18grxkQD')
  .property('createdAt', '2019-04-30T06:09:43.732259')
  .property('updatedAt', '2019-04-30T06:09:43.732259')
  .property('name', 'Advocacy & Human Rights')
```

Unexpectedly, this query is creating 4 new vertexes with different `id` values but with otherwise identical properties (note: `id` is a cosmos db property and is different from the `docId` property I am specifying above).

I'm executing this query in the Azure CosmosDB online portal.

Can anyone help me understand why 4 vertexes are being created instead of 1?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ok, the error was beginning the query with `g.V()`. The following query works as expected:

```
g.addV('ImpactArea')
 .property('partitionKey', '1')
 .property('docId', 'N3TWjll8Ryba18grxkQD')
 .property('createdAt', '2019-04-30T06:09:43.732259')
 .property('updatedAt', '2019-04-30T06:09:43.732259')
 .property('name', 'Advocacy & Human Rights')
```

What I think was happening: my graph has 4 existing vertices in it. `g.V()` was selecting those 4 vertices and then the `addV()` portion of the query was being executed for each vertex.